# Invert nvd3.js legend click function

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

So, in nvd3 charts, clicking on a legend entry basically filters that out of the chart window (for instance in the case of area charts). I want to invert this functionality..i.e. show the particular chart when its corresponding legend is shown and hide all the others...is there a way to do it?

It is similar to what happens when user hits the chart itself (i.e. only the one that is clicked is expanded and rest of the streams hide).

I am referring to this example: http://nvd3.org/ghpages/stackedArea.html

Answer (score 3):

There's a `radioButtonMode` that should do exactly what you want. You should be able to set this on the chart, i.e.

```
 chart.radioButtonMode(true);
```